# C# Custom time value in DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, winforms

I have my datetimepicker value showing only date and this gets the current time on my system to fill up the missing time. I need to have it as `d/MM/yyyy 12:00:00 AM` and `d/MM/yyyy 11:59:59 PM`

Comment: It's not clear what you mean - how are you expecting it to display two values at the same time?

Comment: On the the datetimepicker: just pick the date, then whatever date you have make the time 12:00:00 AM

Comment: You could use `DateTime.Date` to get the first and then create the second from the first.

Comment: So where does 11:59:59 come in? This question is *really* unclear...

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm guessing the OP wants a beginning of the day and end of the day `DateTime`.  Though an exclusive beginning of the next day would work better.  Some example code would help as it seems weird that the current time would get filled in from the date picker.

Comment: @JonSkeet There are 2 datetimepickers: Start and End.

Comment: Just use endDate = endDate.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1)

Comment: @JoshuaMasangcay In that case it's probably better to make the time always midnight and if you want a time span for a specific day the start would be that day and the end would be the next day, then do an inclusive start and exclusive end. Or just add a day to the end date if you want a beginning and end for the same day to cover that entire days time.

Comment: How were we meant to know that there were two pickers? *Please* put more effort when asking questions - see http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree I was guessing there was one picker and they wanted to create two `DateTime`s from it.

Comment: @juharr "it seems weird that the current time would get filled in from the date picker" I believe the current date/time is the default value, and changing the date in the GUI does not change the time.

Comment: @DStanley Interesting, I would have assumed it would default to midnight just like if you use the `DateTime` ctor that only takes year, month, and day.

Comment: @HansPassant .AddMilliseconds(-1) would be better, just in case? or even .AddTicks(-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There are 2 datetimepickers: Start and End

If you want to use those values and just compare the dates regardless of time, format your `DateTimePicker` to just show the date, then either:

1. Take the `Date` portion of the selected values and compare them to the `Date` portion of the input:

   ```
   if(myDate.Date >= dateStart.Date && myDate.Date <= dateEnd.Date)
   ```
2. Add one day to the end date and use an exclusive comparison:

   ```
   if(myDate >= dateStart.Date && myDate < dateEnd.Date.AddDays(1))
   ```

If you don't care about the time then don't mess with it - don't try to set the time on the second date to `11:59:59 PM`

Answer (score 2):

If you pick day 9/2/2015 for start and 9/3/2015 for end

This will give you the start date of 9/2/2015 12:00 AM:

```
string start = dtp1.Value.Date.ToString();
```

This will give you the end date of 9/2/2015 11:59 PM:

```
string end = dtp2.Value.Date.AddSeconds(-1).ToString();
```

if you want 9/3/2015 11:59 PM you could do:

```
string end = dtp2.Value.Date.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1).ToString();
```

Comment: .AddMilliseconds(-1) would be better, just in case? or even .AddTicks(-1)

Comment: Depends on the precision you are looking for. By default DateTime does not output milliseconds in the ToString() method. For most comparisons it would be simpler just to deal with seconds. If you want milliseconds to do any comparison you would need us a IFormatProvider with ToString().